# Import documents into sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have an application that searches word documents (.doc and .docx) that are stored on a File Server.  I'm trying to import these documents to MSSql Server so that I can take advantage of the Full Text Search functionality there.

I have a table that contains information about local hearings.  Each local hearing has the record stored as a .doc or .docx file on a file server, with the location of the file stored as a column in the table.

I'd like to either store the document in a column in the original table, or set up a table with the documents in it and a FK back to the original table.  Which would be the best solution?  Then, how do I structure it?  Do I save the document as varbinary(max)?  I've seen articles that say store the document as an image file, but not how to go about doing it.

Comment: Well, I got a -1, how can I improve the question?

Comment: Maybe you should try FileTable and then create FTS on it. [Full Text Searches on Documents in FileTables](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/full-text-searches-on-documents-in-filetables/)

Comment: stored the document as varbinary(max), storing it as an image is deprecated.